# GCC rotate implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, gcc, std

I need to write a C++ implementation of rotate that is highly optimized for random access iterators (RAIs). The distribution of the input iterators is unknown.

I have seen two common algorithms for rotate before:

1. Just reverse the ranges. This results in 2 writes per element

```cpp
template<RAI>
RAI rotate(RAI _first, RAI _middle, RAI _last) {
  std::reverse(_first, _middle);
  std::reverse(_middle, _last);
  std::reverse(_first, last);
  return _first + _last - _middle;
}
```

2. Let `n=_last-_first` and `d=_middle-_first`

```
template<RAI>
RAI rotate(_first, _middle, _last) { 
    int GCD= gcd(d, n); 
    for (int i = 0; i < GCD; i++) { 
        int temp = *(first+i); 
        int j = i; 
        for (;;) { 
            int k = j + d; 
            if (k >= n) 
                k = k - n; 
            if (k == i) 
                break; 
            *(first+j) = std::move(*(first+k)); 
            j = k; 
        } 
        *(first+j) = temp; 
    } 
}
```

Oddly enough, the [GCC implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/2b16b231946bdc15d17ae33af3cbdfc731904d47/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1316) includes the code for GCD and even says its used to help the rotate algorithm, however the actual rotate algorithm never even uses it. The GCC rotate algorithm is below:

```cpp
template<typename _RandomAccessIterator>
_RandomAccessIterator
__rotate(_RandomAccessIterator __first,
     _RandomAccessIterator __middle,
     _RandomAccessIterator __last,
     random_access_iterator_tag)
{
  // concept requirements
  __glibcxx_function_requires(_Mutable_RandomAccessIteratorConcept<
              _RandomAccessIterator>)

  typedef typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::difference_type
_Distance;
  typedef typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::value_type
_ValueType;

  _Distance __n = __last   - __first;
  _Distance __k = __middle - __first;

  if (__k == __n - __k)
  {
    std::swap_ranges(__first, __middle, __middle);
    return __middle;
  }

  _RandomAccessIterator __p = __first;
  _RandomAccessIterator __ret = __first + (__last - __middle);

  for (;;)
  {
    if (__k < __n - __k)
    {
      if (__k == 1)
      {
        _ValueType __t = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__p);
        _GLIBCXX_MOVE3(__p + 1, __p + __n, __p);
        *(__p + __n - 1) = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__t);
        return __ret;
      }
    _RandomAccessIterator __q = __p + __k;
    for (_Distance __i = 0; __i < __n - __k; ++ __i)
    {
      std::iter_swap(__p, __q);
      ++__p;
      ++__q;
    }
    __n %= __k;
    if (__n == 0)
      return __ret;
    std::swap(__n, __k);
    __k = __n - __k;
  } else  {
      __k = __n - __k;
      if (__k == 1)
      {
        _ValueType __t = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(__p + __n - 1));
        _GLIBCXX_MOVE_BACKWARD3(__p, __p + __n - 1, __p + __n);
        *__p = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__t);
        return __ret;
      }
      _RandomAccessIterator __q = __p + __n;
      __p = __q - __k;
      for (_Distance __i = 0; __i < __n - __k; ++ __i)
      {
        --__p;
        --__q;
        std::iter_swap(__p, __q);
      }
      __n %= __k;
      if (__n == 0)
        return __ret;
      std::swap(__n, __k);
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand why this is faster than the first two I showed above? Consider the section below:

```cpp
_RandomAccessIterator __q = __p + __k;
for (_Distance __i = 0; __i < __n - __k; ++ __i)
{
  std::iter_swap(__p, __q);
  ++__p;
  ++__q;
}
```

if `k` is small, then in that loop, nearly every location will be swapped twice, and that's only on one iteration of the outer `while` loop. So how is this faster than the algorithms above that presumably only perform at most 2 operations per position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sublist-reversing implementation does one swap for every element.  The GCC implementation does at *most* one swap for every element, but maybe less because it has several early termination conditions.

In the particular loop you point to, for example, does `n-k` swaps, but after that `n` is reduced to `k` before the next iteration, so it satisfies the "at most one swap for every element" rule.  If it turned out that `n` was divisible by `k`, though, then the job is already done and it can exit.